# Infinite loop when trying to launch a symbolic-link to a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, symbolic-link, error-handling

I am trying to create a symbolic-link by using:

`$ ln -s path/to/foo.sh ~/.local/bin/bar`

In the path where foo.sh is executed there is another file, named `foo`.

The following bash-script executes successfully when launched directly from the terminal (i.e. $ ./foo.sh), however, when I use the symbolic-link `bar`, it throws an error:

```
# foo.sh

  1 #!/usr/bin/env bash
  2  appname=`basename $0 | sed s,\.sh$,,`
  3 
  4  dirname=`dirname $0`
  5  tmp="${dirname#?}"
  6 
  7  if [ "${dirname%$tmp}" != "/" ]; then
  8  dirname=$PWD/$dirname
  9  fi
 10  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$dirname
 11  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 12  $dirname/$appname $*
```

I don't understand why i get the following error, when I try to launch, script above from the symbolic link `bar`:

**bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1**

Comment: Your question makes it sound like it happens only when launching it from the symlink. Does the error still show up when running it directly?

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for the quick reply. The error does not show up when running the application directly. It only happens when launching it from the symlink.

Comment: Your script trims .sh so running it from foo.sh gets you "No such file...", but then you run it as foo nothing get trimmed and you get an infinite loop.

Comment: @bac0n, I updated the question to clarify the issue. 

The .sh gets trimmed because there is another file with the same name (without the .sh) in the execution directory. Btw, this is not my script, so I'm trying to figure out why I cannot launch such script from a symbolic-link

Comment: the comment still applies ... if you run ./bar you will end up executing `$dirname/$appname $*` ./bar again. (if you name the link bar.sh it will exec bar), the script by it self doesnt make sense... maybe if you describe what you intend to do there may be a better solution

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer and detailed comments @bac0n =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve symlink before processing the file.

*foo.sh*

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Mark variable for export.
declare -xi LVL

# Resolve absolute pathname.
filename=$(realpath "$0")

# Strip .sh suffix from file and check for exec bit.
((LVL++ < 1)) && [[ -x "${filename%.sh}" ]] || exit 1

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${filename%/*}"

# Run it!
"${filename%.sh}" "$@"
```

*foo*

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@"
```

Now we can  create a symlink:

```
$ ln -s /path/to/foo.sh bar
```

<sup>Regardless of the symlink's name, it is the file foo that will be executed.</sup>